# How do I compile for the device without a certificate?

Tags: iphone

I may just be looking in all the wrong places, but is there no way to compile a Cocoa Touch application for ARM without paying for a developer account and certificate?

**EDIT:** To clarify: I am trying to build for a jailbroken device. I simply want to test code on-device without paying for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have jailbroken your iPhone/iPod Touch an Apple iPhone Developer account is required.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to like this answer, but I and everyone else on SO will tell you that developing for a jailbroken device is 10 times worse than developing legitimately with a developer account.  It's not really that expensive, and if you don't have a mac, a low end Mac Mini isn't all that costly either.  If you would just want to get some mobile handset practice in, might I suggest developing with Google's Android.  The SDK is free and you can get a nifty plugin for Eclipse that has a device emulator as well as a GUI builder.  The only downside is that the device support is minimal at the moment.  But hey, you can be on the bleeding edge of a technological revolution.

Comment: hehe - I'm not "developing" anything for distribution - I just want to be able to write some toys for myself, without having to pay for the developer license.